# What would be the logic behind a Dropbox Syncing Note Taking Application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, dropbox

Can anyone please suggest some logic behind a an application that syncs notes with one's DropBox Account?

Consider me a newb.

I'm thinking it should somewhere be around these lines:

1. The app takes notes.
2. The user has to input in his dropbox credentials.
3. Everytime a new note is created, it MUST be synced to his dropbox account.

What would be the various APIs that are to be implemented?

Comment: See http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=08b851b9-af80-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to start thinking about using Dropbox web service APIs to upload the notes to Dropbox.

Some resources to start with:

- [Dropbox Developer portal to learn about using Dropbox API](http://www.dropbox.com/developers)
- [Sample implementation of API for .Net for use or study](http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/)

Following steps above should get your started in the right direction... One suggestion on cloud storage based design... It's best to also have some kind of local storage on the mobile device to act as an offline buffer, just in case user writes a note when they have no internet access. Write the cloud upload/sync code to run in the background.

Have fun!

Comment: I went to the first site, it states "SDKs for iOS, Android, Python, Ruby, and Java". So about WP7?

Comment: I believe a form of operation that I must follow should be this:
1. Load the Application.
2. The User must enter his DropBox credentials where the authentication must succeed.
3. Make the user enter the note contents and note title.
4. The Note is stored as .txt on the IsolatedStorage.
5. That Note is stored on his DropBox from the IsolatedStorage.

Am I right? Please suggest and advice.

_I have applied for the Dropbox Authentication and have the app key and app secret._